# Clang on Cygwin

Tags: c++, cygwin, clang

I just installed Clang on Cygwin and when I `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, I am getting this error:

```
In file included from foo.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/include/c++/i686-pc-cygwin/bits/stdc++.h:101:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/include/c++/condition_variable:39:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/include/c++/mutex:707:10: error: thread-local storage is not supported for the current
      target
  extern __thread void* __once_callable;
         ^
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/include/c++/mutex:708:10: error: thread-local storage is not supported for the current
      target
  extern __thread void (*__once_call)();
         ^
2 errors generated.
```

Including any of `condition_variable`, `future` and `mutex` is resulting in this error.
I don't need any of those headers so I simply commented them in `stdc++.h` Besides that, what can I do to resolve these errors?

PS. I use `bits` for competitive programming as it avoids including so many other headers.